# For all $r \in R$, define a set $M(r)= \lbrace x \in M : rx=0\rbrace $. Prove that $M(r) \cap M(s) = M(\gcd (r,s))$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Suppose $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, where $R$ is a PID. For all $r \in R$, define a set $M(r)= \lbrace x \in M : rx=0\rbrace $. Prove that $M(r) \cap M(s) = M(\gcd (r,s))$.

I manage to prove the LHS is subset of RHS. I can't manage to prove another subset direction. Can anyone give some hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define, for a general $R$-module $M$, the set $M(I)$ for $I$ an ideal of $R$ to be the set $\{x\in M:Ix=0\}$. Let's then claim that $M(I)\cap M(J)=M((I,J))$. Indeed, note that $x\in M(I)\cap M(J)$ if and only if $Ix=Jx=0$. Evidently then $(I,J)x=0$, so that $x\in M((I,J))$. Conversely, if $x\in M((I,J))$ then $Ix,Jx\subseteq (I,J)x=0$ so that $x\in M(I)\cap M(J)$.

Now, how does the above help you?